# How to zip (and unzip) byte[] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, zip, byte, unzip

How can I zip (and unzip) a byte array in C#?

Is it efficient to use zip/unzip on byte arrays with less than 100 elements?

Comment: Do you mean specifically the ZIP file format, or do you mean general compression (like gzip)?

Answer (score 5):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is the library I have used to handle zip/unzip in .NET . If you don't care about the format and if you are just looking for a compression technique, you could look into GZipStream class that's built into .Net framework. Here's [an example.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream) .

Compression is one thing that's highly subjective based on the content. You could do a few tests with your elements to get get an average compression ratio and then you can decide whether or not it's worth the overhead.