# DotNetZipLib + Krakatoa PRT + C#

Tags: c#, zlib, dotnetzip, pdc

so I am writing a C# converter that converts between Maya PDC particle caches and Krakatoa PRT particle caches. I can read and write the PDC files no problem, but I am having issues with the PRT format. http://www.thinkboxsoftware.com/krak-prt-11-file-format/

The PRT format uses ZLib to compress the particle data at the end of the file. I am looking at DotNetZipLib, but am unsure how to feed it a byte array and have DotNetZipLib inflate the byte array into readable data.

Is there a simple way to use DotNetZipLib with byte arrays? I'm hoping for a simple Inflate(bytes[]) method or similar. I don't want to create an actual zip file, but instead infalte a byte array in part of a binary file.

Any info will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create zip file from byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217077/create-zip-file-from-byte)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163094/how-to-zip-and-unzip-byte-in-c